# windows can't show flashdisk

Tags: windows-xp, windows-explorer

It just happened recently, it shows in Device Manager, it also appear in Disk Management, and also, I can open it, but I can't explore it? Here's some screenshot

In Device Manager:

[image]

In Disk Management:

[image]

I tried to change letter but nothing happened, and If I right-click and open, this happened:

[image]

and from explore, there's no drive (H:)

[image]

it happens to every flashdrive and every slot, how do I fix this?

Comment: Can you assign another letter to the Lexar drive in Disk Management? Also, is the drive recognized in Device Manager?

Comment: @DoktoroReichard I already tried to change letter, nothing change. And I already mentioned, it appeared in Device Manager. I don't know what's wrong with this

Comment: Is there data on this device that you need, or can it be re-partitioned? If you can wipe it, i suggest using DiskPart to re-partition the device

Comment: @student080705639 I suggest, if you can, to reboot if you already have not. In case the problem is still there, [this situation](http://superuser.com/a/707631/458082) looks similar to yours